# Datatable 1.10 borra datos al filtrar

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

Estoy insertando datos en una tabla con datatable, al momento de usar el filtro este filtra, pero borra los datos que ya estaban cargados en la tabla.

```
<div class="jarviswidget jarviswidget-color-blueDark" id="wid-id-2" data-widget-editbutton="false">

                <header>
                  <span class="widget-icon"> <i class="fa fa-table"></i> </span>


                </header>

                <!-- widget div-->
                <div>

                  <!-- widget edit box -->
                  <div class="jarviswidget-editbox">
                    <!-- This area used as dropdown edit box -->

                  </div>
                  <!-- end widget edit box -->

                  <!-- widget content -->
                  <div class="widget-body no-padding">

                    <table id="tabla" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hove tabla_ot" width="100%">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Dato1</th>
                          <th>Dato2</th>
                          <th>Dato3</th>
                          <th>Dato4</th>
                          <th>Dato5</th>
                          <th>Dato6</th>
                          <th>Dato7</th>
                          <th>Dato8</th>
                          <th>Dato9</th>
                          <th>Dato10</th>
                          <th>Dato11</th>
                          <th>Dato11</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                       <!-- los datos se cargan aca , pero al usar el filtro de datatable se borran-->
                      </tbody>
                    </table>

                  </div>
                  <!-- end widget content -->

                </div>
                <!-- end widget div -->

              </div>
<!-- agrego el filtro y el paginado-->
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $('#tabla').DataTable( {
    scrollY: 300,
    paging: true
} );


 <!-- inserto los datos al tbody con jquery-->
 $.each(obj.lista, function (ind, elem) { 

    $('#tabla > tbody').html('<tr id="token()" class="row_ot" onclick="Redirec('+elem.valor1+')"><td>'+elem.valor2+'</td><td>'+elem.valor3+'</td><td>'+elem.valor4+'</td><td>'+elem.valor5+'</td><td>'+elem.valor6+'</td><td>'+elem.valor7+'</td><td>'+elem.valor8+'</td><td>'+elem.valor9+'</td><td>'+elem.valor10+'</td><td>'+elem.valor11+'</td><td>'+elem.valor12+'</td><td>'+elem.valor13+'</td></tr>');     
    });
```

Los datos se cargan al comienzo al momento de buscar aunque encuentre coincidencia borra los datos del `tbody`, se me ocurre que quizás hay una función de datable que cancela ese comportamiento

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué haces primero llamas al plugin `$(...).Datatables({...})` o insertas la informacion en la tabla?

Comment: primero llamo al plugin

Comment: intenta primero cargar los datos en la tabla y después llamas al plugin, ¿Te sucede lo mismo?

Comment: sucede exactamente lo mismo estimado :c

Comment: el `.each()` de donde lo obtienes? es una solicitud ajax?

Comment: exacto , si uso php esto no sucede , solo al usar ajax, por los datos no estan fisicamente escritos.

Comment: Puedes poner en tu pregunta como haces la peticion ajax

Comment: cambiare la forma en que lo realizo , lo realizare con php muchas gracias por al ayuda.

Comment: Mira datatables tiene la opción de Server-Side, deberías revisarlo si realizas solicitudes ajax.

Answer (score 0):

DataTables guarda internamente los datos para sus propósitos.

Te recomiendo hacer esto antes de editar la tabla, agregando filas de la manera que lo haces.

```
 $('#tabla').DataTable().clear().destroy();
```

Lo que hace que el contenido de tu tabla se elimine y DataTable remueva todo dato interno que tenga sobre tu tabla.

Luego insertás con tu bucle los nuevos tr, y entonces reinicializás DataTable

```
 $('#tabla').DataTable({
    scrollY: 300,
    paging: true
});
```

Esto soluciona tu problema.

Answer (score -1):

Necesitas destruir los datos cargados en la tabla, cuando se renderiza la tabla tiene cargado las posiciones y los elementos y al agregarlo así no mantiene esos datos

```
$('#tabla').dataTable().fnDestroy();
```

luego has el insert y cargalo (has una función donde tengas tu tabla y sólo lo llamas para levantarlo)

```
const table = cargarTabla();
```